# Identify Painting Chinese or Japanese? (Characters identified: 華岳 洪氏)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy, transcription

I bought a scroll painting. It looks very old painting. It is a very beautiful painting but I want to know the artist name and what it is written in there.

[image: Painting]

Kindly help me in identifying this.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score -1):

It must be 村上华岳 (Kagaku Murakami). He was a Japanese painter and illustrator who lived between 1888 to 1939.

Comment: Thanks for responding, that is really a great help. May I know what is the first red seal means and what is written in black ink. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Does anybody can give more information about the artist name? Also how we can identify the characters?

Comment: @Sachin The 2 black character is literally 華岳. The first red seal has the same content: 2 characters but in ancient Chinese seal font.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to this, may I know which auction house is good for selling these kind of paintings.